# file_get_contents https with header authorization

Tags: php, https, header, authorization

I am trying to authenticate with this site 
https://vatstats.net/api/v1/flights/ via headers with `file_get_contents` with this code:

```
$opts = array(
                'http'=>array(
                    'method'=>"GET",
                    'header'=>"Content-Type: application/json en\r\n" .
                    "Authorization: Token 7f0c76c1930e9519e3408bebfaef79524db6185b\r\n"
                )
            );

$response = file_get_contents("https://vatstats.net/api/v1/flights/?format=json", false, stream_context_create($opts));

echo $response;
```

But for some reason it fails. The API instructions are these:

> All requests to the API must be sent with the API token provided
>   above. Without the token only demo information will be shown which is
>   five records per url. This token must be in the Authorization header.
>
> The key should be prefixed by the string literal "Token", with
>   whitespace separating the two strings.

As an example: `Authorization: Token fd705d56d3a02d46a23d9dc356334f923ff54aa6`

Comment: Fails with what error?

Comment: You may not want to post your tokens on the Internet.

Comment: No error it just keeps showing only 5 records